# phpMyAdmin page is not started it gives me 404 error

Tags: phpmyadmin

I installed all packages Apache, MySQL, PHP, but my phpMyAdmin is not working.

```
mitesh@mitesh-Inspiron-N5010:~$ sudo apt-get install phpmyadmin

[sudo] password for mitesh: 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
phpmyadmin is already the newest version (4:4.5.4.1-2ubuntu2).
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/52469/discussion-on-question-by-kaliya-mitesh-myphpadmin-page-is-not-started-it-gives).

Comment: do to remove the line you see `echo "ServerName localhost" | sudo tee /etc/apache2/conf-available/fqdn.conf &&  sudo e2enconf fqdn`